# check what process was causing the problem of high cpu load

Tags: server, nginx, wordpress

I'm running nginx wordpress server in KVM using 12.04 server x86. It was running very well about 4 month until 2 hours ago. I found that my website is down and no ping response. Virt-manager logged high cpu load(plz see the picture below) before unexpected shut down. I want to know what process caused unexpected shutdown. The following log files make me think my server is attacked. Any suggestions and help would be appreciated.

[image]

`kern.log` and `syslog` showed me same output.

Nov 11 03:54:11 www kernel: [1344541.156239] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.
0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2

Nov 11 03:54:11 www kernel: [1344541.156315] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=0101:080a:2334:c90
0:0100:0000:0000:0000 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=130 CODE=0

`/nginx/access.log` showed me

119.235.237.17 - - [11/Nov/2012:03:45:29 +0900] "GET /blog HTTP/1.1" 200 30493 "-" "Yeti/1.0 (NHN Corp.; http://help.naver.com/robots/)"
my-server-ip - - [11/Nov/2012:11:05:30 +0900] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=13 HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "WordPress/3.4.2; http://mywebsite.com"

Server turned on in here.
119.235.237.16 - - [11/Nov/2012:11:05:30 +0900] "GET /blog HTTP/1.1" 200 32935 "-" "Yeti/1.0 (NHN Corp.; http://help.naver.com/robots/)"

Comment: "Yeti is the crawler for Naver, a popular Korean search engine" (http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/). Perhaps this "attack" was an unintentional DOS when Yeti began crawling your site? Have you done any previous load-testing of your site?

Comment: Thanks for heads up @LarsRohrbach
Oh yeah, just figured out about yeti stuff. 
I've never tried load-testing before. I'm doing that right now in here http://loadimpact.com/. Will you tell me how I can use the result from load-testing?

Comment: Load-testing could help confirm whether your site responds well to demand, or reproduces a high-cpu-load issue, for example.

Comment: Alright Thanks for your info. I found interesting results. style.css loads really slow when it comes in load-testing. 81.16ms to load. javascript is taking more than that,but I think js never been fast.

Comment: Decided block ip range of 119.235.237.0/24 in nginx

Comment: Did the load-testing ever reproduce a high-cpu-load situation?  Do you think this has helped solve your problem?

Comment: The load-testing didn't reproduce high cpu load. It won't even reach 0.7 in htop while load-testing. The crawler for Naver seems ignore robots.txt. Sorry to Naver but blocked them in iptables. It did help for now. Thanks @LarsRohrbach for help. I should close this question but don't know how. oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the web access may be coincidental, it's certainly possible that
the Korean web crawler Naver created an unintentional Denial Of Service (DOS)
against your site by aggressively crawling it.  This can potentially crash
nginx or your OS, or it can just make them too slow to respond effectively
to new requests.

Using a website load-tester can help to determine just how much load your site
can handle, and perhaps reproduce whether a heavy load could indeed cause a 
problem to your webserver.  Depending on the detail provided by the load-tester,
you may be able to determine whether there are any improvements you can make
to your site code or configuration to improve response.

You can also choose just to block the offending web client, or create/modify your
local [robots.txt file](http://www.robotstxt.org/)
to block a specific crawler (e.g. Yeti) or specify what part of your site they
should not crawl.  Sorry to hear in your comments, but apparently Yeti isn't 
honoring your robots.txt file, so blocking their IP range seems reasonable.